# Gui for Service Broker Dashboard

Tags: html, sql, authentication, ssis

We have a service broker dashboard that monitors queues on our database.

Its a simple interface that shows the queues, whats still processing/unprocessed (quantity) and the jobs that the queues are linked to.

The issue here is that different people in the company have different levels of access in SQL, hence when lower level users need to view this app, it crashes citing Authentication issues.

I am thinking of creating a Web Interface to display the queues and quantities processing/unprocessed and status of jobs and the queues with buttons to restart them and view the log.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'll answer the question you did not ask, namely how to address the problem of an application that performs a certain task requiring privileges (eg. VIEW SERVER STATE required to query the [`sys.dm_broker_activated_tasks`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175029%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)) but without giving the privilege to the user using the application. The best solution is [module signing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102%28v=sql.105%29.aspx): your application is querying the privileged DMV via a stored procedure and you sign the procedure and grant the required privilege to the signature. Read a full example  at [Signing an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/) (the example is pertinent to activation, but it applies just as well to your monitoring app). Of course, you would have to modify the application to interact with the database using stored procedures so you have something to sign.

Now your actual question, which is basically 'how to do a web app'. Is really too broad. Start by following an ASP.Net MVC tutorial for example to get you started. http://www.asp.net/mvc is a great starting point.